# Jenkins - cmd is not recognized

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Environment:

- Master Linux Jenkins server
- Two Windows slave nodes
- The windows slaves are running as a service

First Test

- I create a Pipeline and use a use a "Execute Windows batch command" in the build section
- In the Command box I put "C:\Jenkins\mytest.bat"
- I checked the box "Restrict where this project can be run" and write down the name of the Windows slave
- I built the pipeline and was **successful**

Second Test

- I create a Declarative Pipeline as follows:

  ```
  pipeline {  
      agent { label 'SiebelWindows' }

      stages {
          stage('Test Bat') {
             steps { 
                          bat 'C:\\Jenkins\\mytest.bat'
                          //bat 'start cmd.exe /c C:\\Jenkins\\mytest.bat'
                          //call C:\\Jenkins\\mytest.bat
                          }
                  }
      }
     }
  ```
- In this case the build **FAIL** with error "cmd is not recognized as a internal o external command"

So, why can I run the .bat with a non-declarative pipeline, but fails with a declarative pipeline?

Comment: Is `mytest.bat` executable?

Comment: What happend if you run the second command: `bat 'start cmd.exe /c C:\\Jenkins\\mytest.bat'` ?

Comment: Hi Matt... The file mytest.bat is a windows batch file

Comment: With the second command is the same result, "cmd is not a recognized internal o external command"

Comment: Do you have C:\Windows\system32 in your %PATH%variable of your Windows? The error 'X is not recognized as interntal or external command" usually tells you that a path is missing in your %PATH% variable.

Comment: Yes, in the %PATH% variable we have C:\Windows\system32. I don't know why works fine if I run as a "Execute Windows batch command", but when I create a pipeline as a code (declarative) is not working. Its the same server, the same command

Comment: @MattSchuchard The mytest.bat is a very simple batch file. Its only have a "dir" command

Comment: I am in a similar situation and I believe that it is related to the background mode explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149603/why-am-i-not-able-to-run-batch-file-in-jenkins-pipeline-running-in-windows-10

Comment: Question:  Does `C:\\Jenkins\\mytest.bat` use _CMD_ or _START_ within it?

Answer (score 12):

When I display the "Path" and the "PATH" variables, this was the result

[Original_Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqVOJ.jpg)

The solution was redefine the PATH enviorement variable, like this

```
environment {

    PATH = "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32"

}
```

@JustAProgrammer aske me if C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 was in the PATH of my Windows machine, and that is correct, but seems like Jenkins master do not know the slave's Windows Path.

I resolve my issue, but I still looking for a complete solution, I need to set the PATH enviorement variable with ALL the path, no only C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

Comment: i would suggest to use  "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32;%PATH%" here else there are chances that we might lost some old PATH values set earlier and that might cause even bigger problem

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the problem too although the path variable looks correct, check the length of the `PATH` variable (`echo %PATH%`). Windows has some restriction of the length of an environment variable (see [Microsoft DevBlog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100203-00/?p=15083)).
Remove some entries or set the `PATH` explicit like already mentioned.

Check also the configuration of the [Environment Injector Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/), which can override the default user and system `PATH` variable.