# error running batch cmd with jenkins from jenkinsfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I try to use jenkins to run a simple batch command from a jenkinsfile in my git repo:

```
  ...
  steps {
      script{
        bat "git status"
      }
   }
...
```

but it gives me always this error:

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
13:27:41 'cmd' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
13:27:41 ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

In english : cmd is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I checked that jenkins was executed on the right windows node.

Have you any clue how to solve this ?
thanks

Comment: And my windows path contains "c:\windows\system32"

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply !
I foud a solution with this previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488509/jenkins-cmd-is-not-recognized

It seems that Jenkins overwrite the PATH env variable by default.

Comment: It seems that Jenkins overwrite the PATH env variable by default with linux ones ?
I specified  every windows paths I need in the PATH env var in my jenkinsfile and it works now.
this is not the best solution in my opinion. If you have a better one I ll be glad to know it  !