# 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm running a simple pipeline code to run batch script with following -

```
node('node-ip') {

    parallel 'Checking Database': {
            script {
                bat 'dir'
            }
    }
}
```

but this results into following error -

`'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Can you please help to understand what could be wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins - cmd is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488509/jenkins-cmd-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Thanks @Melkjot, this helped! I had to add path - `C:\Windows\system32` in Node configuration and it resolved the issue.